# Underscore bindAll, explicit method naming

Tags: javascript, coding-style, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using `_.bindAll` in lots of my Backbone.Views.

```
_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addOne', 'addAll', 'someFunctionA', 'someFunctionB');
```

While refactoring this becomes quite tedious as I need to keep the views methods and the name listings in sync. Both ways this often leads to simple errors.

As there is a short version of `bindAll`, which would eliminate this need, I am wondering what drawbacks (performance, readability, flexibility, ..) do exist and do you consider them acceptable to gain a bit of a productivity boost.

```
_.bindAll(this);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no practical performance penalty for using that form of bindAll. However, it will be a pain if you do not want a method bound to `this` for some reason.

However, you may find that you do not need to use bindAll as often as you think. All methods that are bound to event handlers (with the events hash) are automatically bound to `this`.

Also, when you are explicitly binding an event, you can pass the `this` binding in the third param. For example:

`this.model.bind('change', this.render, this)`

Comment: Thanks. My increased usage is due to an app-wide eventBus, where automatic binding is not in place :/ Thx for pointing out to bind `this`, directly when I declare the model binding (Note: I think it should read: `this.model.on`). Lastly, I am curious: What are scenarios, where I do not want my views methods to be bound to the view itself?

Comment: Right, Backbone 0.9 now uses "on" instead of "bind" as in 0.5 and before. In the "view world" I find that you almost always want `this` to be the view. But if you are really attached to the jQuery convention of `this` being an event target then this might not work for you. Personally, I like the consistency in use of `this`.

Answer (score 4):

I'v used `_.bindAll(this)` in backbone project for a while. After profiling the code I'v realized that calls to `_.bindAll` takes notable part of all the function calls.
Based on the results of the performance test http://jsperf.com/underscore-bindall-this-vs-bindall-this-params
it seems that explicit method naming is more performant (especially for objects with a lot of functions)